# Forwarding AnyEvent::Log messages to a callback if certain requirements are met

Tags: perl, logging, daemon, anyevent

I am working on a project that uses AnyEvent Log in the main program as well as several dependent modules/packages. I currently have each module writing to it's own context, and all contexts are added to the main programs context as slaves. This project is part of a much larger project, and in addition to writing out a local log file, there are certain messages that I would like to send to a remote program which will then be responsible for presenting the messages to users.

The problem is that in order to send to the remote program, I have to have a piece of information that is only available from the main program, so it's not feesible to just implement a method at the package level to send messages. The piece of information I need is more or less a transaction id, and the log messages are interesting events from a particular transaction.

The main program has 2 contexts ( main , secondary ). The messages I am interested in will either come from the secondary ctx OR one of the package/module contexts. I am interested in only sending info - crit level messages to users, but ONLY WHEN the txID exists in the main program. I ALWAYS want messages to be written to my local log file regardless of whether or not a deployment is running. I would like this to be something that I setup in the main program rather than in a module because the modules are tasked to do certain thing and shouldn't even be aware of the fact that there is an ID associated with the task at hand.

Here is a quick breakdown of the log configuration specific code in the main program.

```
# Immediately after Proc::Daemon::Init
my $logger = AnyEvent::Log::ctx "desman";

# configure is done before daemonization to allow for --nodaemon
sub configure {
  my ( $level, $file ) = @_;
  $AnyEvent::Log::FILTER->level($level);
  $AnyEvent::Log::LOG->log_to_file($file);
}

sub log_event {
  ... logic to send messages as tx event ...
}
sub worker_init {

  threads->create(sub {
    $logger->attach( my $worklog = AnyEvent::Log::ctx "worker" );
     ... more stuff for worker specifics ...
  });
}
```

Ideally, I would be able to use one or both of log_cb and fmt_cb to handle the formatting and sending of messages to the remote program using the log_event sub. I have tried a few different things, and so far I'm stuck.

```
# doesn't seem to do anything
$logger->fmt_cb( sub { ... } );
$logger->log_cb( sub { ... } );

# broke everything
$AnyEvent::Log::COLLECT->attach( my $evtlog = new AnyEvent::Log::Ctx
  fmt_cb => \&event_formatter,
  log_cb => \&log_event
);
$evtlog->levels('crit','warning','notice','info');
```

I've been searching around for more examples than what's in the docs, but haven't found much yet. Not much of a surprise there since AE::log is pretty much awesome as it is, but anything to help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I figured this out. At some point I must have removed the `log_event` sub which is why the second method listed above was causing all logging to fail. I tried pasting a full explanation of the final result as an Answer to my own question, but my rep here is too low. If anyone else is trying to do the same thing and finds themselves here, I'd be happy to post the complete solution I came up with.